# How to split a Sine wave to two positive and negative parts by real circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, sine

I would like to split a sinusoidal wave to two different positive and negative parts  so that sum of these two parts result the main sinusoidal wave.
i think one way is that using two different branch by diodes to split the positive and negative parts. is there any different real circuit configuration for this purpose?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Bridge Rectifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode_bridge). They are used all the time for converting AC signals into DC, specifically in power supplies.

Comment: yes, but i need to have positive and negative waves separately. thats why i am saying probably two half bridge rectifiers for having both positive and negative parts in two separate signals.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to solve? there maybe a better method than two 1/2 wave rect that are then summed

Comment: Can you perhaps draw a simple graph of the signal you hope to achieve?

Comment: why do you think you need this?  is it for use in the digital domain or analogue?  if it is in the digital it would be simpler to sample and check for the sign bit *IF* you really need to know when the waveform is positive or negative. do you need the actual sinus profile or just that it is positive? ie zero crossing detector?

Comment: it is for analog. i would like separate a sine wave and use two separate signals for next step of my circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends how accurately you want to preserve the shape of each half of the waveform. If accuracy isn't a big concern then using a positive half wave rectifier and a negative half wave rectifier gives you what you need: -

[image]

To get a negative rectifier just reverse the diode connection. Be aware that there is a small voltage drop across the diode and this means that the peak of the signal output is somewhat lower than the original sinewave. If the operating frequency is a few hundred Hz or above you'll need to choose a diode that has low reverse recovery time: -

[image]

If you need more accuracy you can use an op-amp precision rectifier: -

[image]

Comment: Yes, i had this solution and thanks so much. if my frequency is 200 khz or even more , diode still can handle the high frequency sinwave?

Comment: @Diana it depends on the diode and the power you wish for it to pass thru to the load. You need to come clean about this.

Comment: the amplitude of sinewave is 10 v and frequency about 500khz or even more. i need to split this signal to two positive and negative signals. diode 1N4148 based on the data sheet might be an element but i am not sure this device can handle the 500khz freqency or not?

Comment: The 1N4148 has a reverse recovery time of about 6 ns - it is one of the fastest types available. You can consider a schottky diode - they don't have a reverse recovery time but they do have more capacitance and this could upset things. Why not download LTSpice (free) and try simulating your circuit.