# How to shift level of my AC signal compared to another AC signal?

Tags: design, level-shifting, level-translation

I want to shift my AC signal level. i have a floating point in my circuit (SINE wave 1 with high amplitude around 350v) which is always changing. on the other hand i have another signal (SINE wave2 with low amplitude) both of them are based on the circuit ground. now, i want to shift one of them compared to another sine wave. i can say that the SINE wave 2 should be a kind of reference (ground) for SINE wave1. 
In summary, i have two AC signal based on the ground and i would like to shift one of them in relation to the second one but the main problem is that the amplitude of one of them is high about 300v.
I wonder if you could help me by suggesting me some circuits configuration for this purpose.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you want to add them together or that you want to add a DC offset to one of them?

Comment: @RogerRowland I want to add them with each other

Comment: So you mean like a [simple op amp summer](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html)?

Comment: YEs, the amplitude  of one of them is high like 350v.

Comment: Ok, I think you need to edit all that information into your question. I'm pretty sure that sort of voltage would kill an op amp.

Comment: so, what is an alternative for that?

Comment: Personally, I don't know, but if you don't edit your question to explain the full problem, you'll only waste time with people posting answers about op amps. The better the question, the better the answers.

Comment: I've read this question several times now and it really is totally unclear as to what you want. If necessary state mathematically (in a formula) what you want but right now the words make no sense.

Comment: A schematic would be really helpful too.

Comment: You might also consider marking answers to previous questions you have asked as "accepted". Here's one that I answered: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195905/how-to-split-a-sine-wave-to-two-positive-and-negative-parts-by-real-circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have two ground-referenced sine signals, and you wish to add them together but the voltages are too large for typical op-amp circuits. One way to do this would be to use a 1:1 transformer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2nDA6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How practical this is will depend on the frequency of the signals, and the impedance of the sources and loads (it might help to add these details to your question). If you have high impedance loads, and thus low power, you'll probably find a suitable transformer very cheaply.  If you need large powers suitable transformers will be large, heavy, and expensive.

Comment: thank you for your help. i looking for a general solution because in this case just an AC signal (sinewave1) is used. but if floating point is DC or AC how we can a solution to shift SINE wave2 based on it?

Comment: Sorry Diana, but I'm not completely clear what you are asking. The circuit sketched above will work for a 'sine1' that is AC, DC or any combination thereof, but sine2 must be AC. If the circuit above is not suitable, you could consider an opamp summer circuit with a high voltage opamp from Apex Microtechnology (e.g. PA91)

Comment: @ Jack B  , thanks so much for your help. i have some question from practical aspect, if sine1 is high voltage and with 200khz frequency, is it possible to design as precise as possible?

Comment: I don't think I can really take the design any further than the sketch above without knowing far more about the circuit: The source of the signals; the voltage and frequency of both; the current flowing; the impedance of the load; the accuracy required on the output; EMC requirements; the regulatory environment etc. etc. And the frequency you're asking about is rather higher than I'm used to working with too. You might have to look elsewhere.